# After state change data binding is not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After login I have landed in `app.mainapp` state this time everything normal.

Now I moved to another state lets say `app.xyz` this time ok.

But when I came back to `app.mainapp` state from `app.xyz` then view in `app.mainapp` state is not updating with data but in the controller data is updating.

Below is my `route.js`

```
$stateProvider
  .state('login', { // Adding state for displaying login page
      url: '/login',
      views: {
          'app@': {
              templateUrl: 'app/components/authentication/login.html',
              controller: 'AuthenticationController as authCtrl'
          }
      }
  })
  .state('app',{
      url:'/',
      views:{
          'app@':{
              templateUrl: 'app/components/header/header.html',
              controller: 'HeaderController',
              controllerAs: 'headerCtrl'
          }
      }
  })
  .state('app.mainapp', { // Adding state for displaying admin pages
      url: 'orders',
      views: {
          'appbody@app': {
              templateUrl: 'app.abc.html',
              controller: 'OrderController as orderCtrl'
          }
      }
  })
  .state('app.history', { // Adding state for displaying admin pages
      url: 'history',
      views: {
          'appbody@app': {
              templateUrl: 'app/xyz.html',
              controller:function(){

              }
          }
      }
  });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

this is `index.html` file

```
<div ng-cloak ui-view="app" style="height: 100%;"></div>
```

this is my `header.html`

```
<div>
    inside header
    <div ui-view="appbody" flex></div>
</div>
```

Please help me why data binding is not working after state change.